# Magento: How to set a parameter in a grid block using Layout?

Tags: magento, layout

I'm trying to set a parameter using `<action method='setMyParam'>`
Then I'm trying to read It in the class block but the parameter it is not set.

I'm tring reading it in the `_prepareLayout()`  method in the block class I guess the problem is caused by this method as wrong chose ...

Any idea ?

Here XML my code ( I think there are no error )

```
<adminhtml_mymod_log>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="mymod/adminhtml_myblock" name="myname.index" >
            <action method="setLogType">
                <params>ship</params>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_mymod_log>
```

**Update:**

The problem is that the`set` method is called after `_prepareLayout()` so, I was right, I should choose some different method to read the param:
- something like `AfterPrepareLayout()` ...

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is nothing like a function `AfterPrepareLayout().`
However, you can use the `_beforeToHtml()`, it is called earlier than `_prepareСolumns()` and `_prepareСollection()` like this:

```
protected function _beforeToHtml()
{
    print_r($this->getLogType());die; // display "ship"
    return parent::_beforeToHtml();
}
```